# SQLite: store data in independent columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database where i store information like name, mobile phone, and so on. This database get many reads and not much writes, so, I added an auto-incrementing id.

I then need to store quite much info per each ids. Those are timestamp (seconds from epoch). I need something like 200 timestamp per user (with hopefully 1000+ users). I need to be able to filter those timestamp quickly (exp. between today and today + 1 week).

A way I solved this was like that:

```
id1  | id2  |  id3 | .... | idn
_________________________________
time | time | time
time | time | time
time |      | time
     |      | time
```

Obviously, I know that this is not ideal (I also need to delete many of these timestamp, so I'm getting an ever-growing/quasi-empty table, but I had no other ideas.

Is it better to use a separate table for every user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to create two tables `Users` and `Events`.

In `Users` you store the users ID, name, and other items that occur *once and only once* per user.

In `Events` you store *one record for each time stamp*.  Each record contains a user's ID, the time value, and any other information that occurs *once and only once for that individual event*.

This is the basis of relational design.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Didn't realize that it was so easy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use separate table and use foreign key to connect back to user (by userId or something that is unique). Your design will bring you to the point where database is not maintainable anymore.

```
+----------+            +----------+
| userId   |            | userId   |
+----------+  <----->   +----------+
| time     |            | name     |
| stamp    |            +----------+
+----------+            | other    |
                        | info...  |
                        +----------+
```

On the right side it should be table with user specific data, and left one is table with time entries.